# Javascript - change value of variable on button click

Tags: javascript

I have an 10 HTML buttons that I need to change the value of a javascript variable when clicked.

```
song2 = "mp3Player/kingRight.mp3";
 function returnVar2(song2) { return this[song2]; }
```

Song2 needs a new URL depending on which button is clicked.

Having a hard time figuring this out.

Answer (score 2):

```
<button id="b1">Button 1</button>
<button id="b2">Button 2</button>
<script>
var b1 = document.getElementById('b1'), b2 = document.getElementById('b2');
var x = "Hello!";
function showX() {
    alert(x);
}
b1.onclick = function() {
    x = "button one";
    showX();
};
b2.onclick = function() {
    x = "button two";
    showX();
};
</script>
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/4UvUv/)

Comment: Thanks, that explained a lot.  I still have one question though - I need the run "function returnVar2(song2)" and have it return "var song2 = x" when the button is clicked.  I have some AS3 code listening for this function and variable return, and I need it to see this on button click.  Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Yeah definitely.  I've just been stuck on this for hours.  My javascript skills are not great...

Comment: Can you add some of the pertinent stuff the demo fiddle I made so I can see how better to assist?

Comment: Ok, your demo has been updated.  I would like to be able to run the function returnVar2(song2) on a button click and have it return the variable song2 with the URL.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div id="mp3buttons">
    <div title="mp3Player/kingRight.mp3">King Right</div>
    <div title="mp3Player/AnotherSong.mp3">Another Song</div>
    etc.
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var mp3buttons = document.getElementById( 'mp3buttons' );

mp3buttons.onclick = function ( e ) {        
    var url = e.target.title;
    // do stuff with this URL
};
```

So, you put your buttons inside a wrapper. For each button, you place the URL inside the `title` attribute (or some other appropriate attribute).

In JavaScript code, you bind a click handler to the wrapper. The clicked button is referenced with `e.target`.